# Word splitting / text parsing with consideration for quotes

Tags: f#

Is the `MoveNext` operation inefficient here?  I really just want to increment an index.  Originally, I had a mutable variable locally in `ExtractTokens` to accommodate this.  I would have to believe that a mutable variable there would have been pretty efficient, but I'm trying hard not to have them.  I can't help but feel that creating a new Record to increment an integer is bad somehow.  I guess I'm wondering what a real-world F# developer would have chosen to do here.

This starts in `ExtractTokens`.  It basically iterates each character in a string.  On spaces it yields the previous word, unless in a quote either single or double.

```
type Quote = 
   | Single
   | Double
   | None

type State = {
   Start : int
   Index : int
   Quote : Quote
   }

let InitState : State = 
   {Start = 0; Index = 0; Quote = None }

let MoveNext (s : State) : State = 
   {s with Index = s.Index + 1}

let FlipQuote (s : State) (text : string) : State = 
   match text.[s.Index], s.Quote with
   | '\'', None   -> {s with Quote = Single}
   | '"' , None   -> {s with Quote = Double} 
   | '\'', Single -> {s with Quote = None}
   | '"' , Double -> {s with Quote = None}
   | _ -> s

let StartNew (s : State) : State = 
   {Start = s.Index; Index = s.Index; Quote = None}

let NotEmpty (s : string) : bool =
   not (System.String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))

let GetToken (s : State) (text : string) : string =
   text.Substring(s.Start, s.Index - s.Start)

let GetChar (s : State) (text : string) : string =
   text.[s.Index].ToString()

let ExtractTokens (text : string) : seq<string> = 
   let rec loop state = 
      seq {
         if (state.Index < text.Length) then
            match text.[state.Index], state.Quote with
            | '"' , _  
            | '\'', _     -> yield! FlipQuote state text |> MoveNext |> loop
            | ' ' , None   
            | '(' , None
            | ')' , None  -> yield  GetToken state text
                             yield  GetChar  state text
                             yield! MoveNext state |> StartNew |> loop 
            | _   , _     -> yield! MoveNext state |> loop
         else
            yield GetToken state text
      }
   loop InitState |> Seq.where NotEmpty
```

**Refactored**

```
type Quote = 
   | Single
   | Double
   | None

type State = {
   Start : int
   Quote : Quote
   }

let InitState : State = 
   {Start = 0; Quote = None }

let FlipQuote (state : State) (index : int) (text : string) : State = 
   match text.[index], state.Quote with
   | '\'', None   -> {state with Quote = Single}
   | '"' , None   -> {state with Quote = Double} 
   | '\'', Single
   | '"' , Double -> {state with Quote = None}
   | _ -> state

let StartNew (state : State) (index : int) : State = 
   {Start = index; Quote = None}

let NotEmpty = 
   System.String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace >> not   

let GetToken (state : State) (index : int) (text : string) : string =
   text.Substring(state.Start, index - state.Start)

let GetChar (index : int) (text : string) : string =
   text.[index].ToString()

let ExtractTokens (text : string) : seq<string> = 
   let rec loop index state = 
      seq {
         if (index < text.Length) then
            match text.[index], state.Quote with
            | '"' , _  
            | '\'', _     -> yield! FlipQuote state index text |> loop (index + 1)
            | ' ' , None   
            | '(' , None
            | ')' , None  -> yield  GetToken state index text
                             yield  GetChar  index text
                             yield! StartNew state (index + 1) |> loop  (index + 1)
            | _   , _     -> yield! state |> loop (index + 1)
         else
            yield GetToken state index text
      }
   loop 0 InitState |> Seq.where NotEmpty
```

Comment: Is it slower than a mutable variable? Definitely yes. Does it matter? _Probably_ not. Here's a rant I wrote recently on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202840/can-non-persistent-data-structures-be-used-in-a-purely-functional-way/40205662#40205662

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I definitely agree with your point of view.  I am of the same mindset.  This example just seemed so local and incorruptible and I did work around it.  I just wasn't sure if the mutable 'i' in what is essentially a for loop, falls into the optimization bucket or is it just being pragmatic.  Sounds like it's optimization.  Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying the below revision is an improvement but it has eliminated the need for `MoveNext`. The penalty is to have the index as a separate argument to `loop` which violates the idea of a state object. One could argue that the index is not a part of the (splitting)state but just an iterator variable and then everything are nicely justified again :-)

```
module RevisedSplitting =

    type String with
        member this.charAt index =
            this.[index]

    type Quote = 
       | Single
       | Double
       | None

    type State = {
       Start : int
       Quote : Quote
       }

    let InitState = 
       {Start = 0; Quote = None }

    let FlipQuote s index (text : string) = 
       match text.charAt index, s.Quote with
       | '\'', None   -> {s with Quote = Single}
       | '"' , None   -> {s with Quote = Double} 
       | '\'', Single -> {s with Quote = None}
       | '"' , Double -> {s with Quote = None}
       | _ -> s

    let StartNew s index = 
       {Start = index; Quote = None}

    let NotEmpty s =
       not (System.String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))

    let GetToken s index text =
       (string text).Substring(s.Start, index - s.Start)

    let GetChar index (text : string) =
       sprintf "%c" (text.charAt index)

    let ExtractTokens (text : string) = 
       let rec loop index state = 
          seq {
             if index < (text |> Seq.length) then
                match text.charAt index, state.Quote with
                | '"' , _  
                | '\'', _     -> yield! FlipQuote state index text |> loop (index + 1)
                | ' ' , None   
                | '(' , None
                | ')' , None  -> yield  GetToken state index text
                                 yield  GetChar  index text
                                 yield! StartNew state (index + 1) |> loop (index + 1)  
                | _   , _     -> yield! state |> loop (index + 1)
             else
                yield GetToken state index text
          }
       loop 0 InitState |> Seq.where NotEmpty
```

Comment: let me write some comments

Comment: 1. Now `NotEmpty` looks not in the style of F#. You can use `>>` [forward composition operator](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/09/fsharp-pipe-forward-and-pipe-backward/) instead: `let NotEmpty =
       System.String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace >> not`

Comment: 2. In function `FlipQuote` two patterns return the same value.

Comment: @FoggyFinder: Thanks for your comments, but maybe they are better aimed at the original post :-). My goal was entirely to get rid of MoveNext

Comment: right right, just didn't want to write another one answer :)

Comment: @HenrikHansen yeah, i like this.  then i'm not copying that record just to increment my loop.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: @FoggyFinder You right.  I'll adjust the FlipQuote to combine the last two cases.  the "IsNullOrWhitespace >> not" is bending my mind a little.  I guess get it, "not" is just another function then?  Makes sense.  Just not used to thinking of it that way.  Thanks!

Comment: @HenrikHansen the "sprintf "%c" (text.charAt index)".  Can you give me some insight into that change?  I'm guessing the "charAt" is more functional that referencing an index directly?  and the "sprintf" vs "ToString"?

Comment: @TBone: I'm not sure charAt is more functional than referencing the index directly, but IMO it nicer to read and it show how to make extension functions in F#. The sprinf is the intrinsic F# string composer. The nice thing about it is that you get immediately response from the inference mechanism if you use the right markup or not for the argument.